# matplotlib combining start and end point

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, spyder

I am trying to fit a data set. When I plot final parameters fit looks lilke in photo. I don't want the line which combining start and end point of x-axis. How can I do that?
Fit look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/heI8d.jpg

```
def solvePlot(self):

    def massFunc(t, a, b, c):
        return a*(t*t)+b*t+c

        #ravel function turns the list to 1dimension for use to fitting.
    self.x = self.Tepoch.ravel()
    self.y = self.TOC.ravel()

    p0 = [2, 0.2, 28, 6.6]
    fitParams, fitCovariances = curve_fit(massFunc, self.x, self.y, p0)

    print fitParams
    print fitCovariances

    sigma = [fitCovariances[0,0], fitCovariances[1,1], fitCovariances[2,2] ]
    plt.plot(self.x, massFunc(self.x, fitParams[0], fitParams[1], fitParams[2]))
    plt.plot(self.x,self.TOC,'o')


    plt.ylabel('O-C')
    plt.xlabel('EPOCH')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: sort your points in x-order.

Comment: On a firt impression I would say that @tcaswell reply is the correct one. In general when you pose a question is better to  give a code that can replicate your error completely, and not only a function. This will help people reproduce and correct your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @tcaswell sorting works for it. I was thinking that part of code is enough thank you too.